# Rabbitmq cluster does not work in openstack cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, openstack, mnesia

When I try to join cluster from 2nd node, always got the error message:

```
[root@dl1-sensu03 rabbitmq]# rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local
```

Clustering node 'rabbit@dl1-sensu03.pan.local' with 'rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local'
Error: {failed_to_cluster_with,['rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local'],
                               "Mnesia could not connect to any nodes."}

In the log, I see this:

=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jan-2018::00:34:31 ===
Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 9 retries left

=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jan-2018::00:34:31 ===
Waiting for Mnesia tables for 30000 ms, 0 retries left

=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jan-2018::00:34:31 ===
Clustering with ['rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local'] as disc node

=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Jan-2018::00:35:38 ===
** Node 'rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local' not responding **
** Removing (timedout) connection **

=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Jan-2018::00:35:38 ===
Mnesia('rabbit@dl1-sensu03.pan.local'): ** ERROR ** mnesia_event got {inconsistent_database, running_partitioned_network, 'rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local'}

And I am sure the port 4369, 5672, 15672, 25672 are working and accessible between two nodes. The same configuration works fine in my VMware ENV previously. I am not sure if there is any special thing in openstack.

Comment: On the fist node, I saw this in sasl log, not sure if this matters: [root@dl1-sensu01 rabbitmq]# cat rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local-sasl.log

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 24-Jan-2018::23:41:05 ===
     Supervisor: {<0.861.0>,rabbit_channel_sup_sup}
     Context:    shutdown_error
     Reason:     shutdown
     Offender:   [{nb_children,1},
                  {name,channel_sup},
                  {mfargs,{rabbit_channel_sup,start_link,[]}},
                  {restart_type,temporary},
                  {shutdown,infinity},
                  {child_type,supervisor}]

Comment: One more thing is: Previously, the cluster name always show short name instead of FQDN, then I ran command rabbitmqctl set_cluster_name 'rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local'. I am sure  I setup the hostname correctly. Not sure what could make rabbitmq always set the cluster name with short name:   [root@dl1-sensu01 rabbitmq]# rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local'
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local']}]},
 {running_nodes,['rabbit@dl1-sensu01.pan.local']},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@dl1-sensu01">>},